# Residue of order 3 -

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series for the function
  \begin{align}
    f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+4)^3}
  \end{align}
  about the isolated singular pole $z = 2i$. What is the pole order? What is the residue at the pole?

My attempt:
  \begin{align}
    f(z) &= \frac{1}{(z^2+4)^3}\\
      &= \frac{1}{(z+2i)^3(z-2i)^3}\\
  \end{align}
  Here we see $z=2i$ is a 3rd order pole.

A Laurent series is defined with respect to a particular non-analytic point $z_0$ and a path of integration C. The path of integration must lie in an annulus surrounding $z_0$ and so
   \begin{align}
     f(z) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n
     % = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n}
     % + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^{n}
   \end{align}
   where
   \begin{align}
     a_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\\
     % &&  \text{Regular Part}&\\
     % b_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{-n-1}} \label{eq:laurentb}
     % && \text{Principle Part} &
   \end{align}
   We find the $a_n$ term using $z_0=2i$,
   \begin{align}
     a_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{\frac{1}{(z+2i)^3(z-2i)^3}}{(z-2i)^{n+1}}\\
     a_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{(z+2i)^3(z-2i)^{n+4}}
   \end{align}
   and from Cauchy's Integral Formula we can find the residue $(n=-1)$ term,
   \begin{align}
     a_{(-1)}&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{(z+2i)^{3}(z-2i)^{-1+4}}\\
     &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{(z+2i)^{3}(z-2i)^{3}}\\
     &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{1}{(z+2i)^{3}(\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{2i})}
      \frac{1}{(z-2i)(\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{2i})}????
   \end{align}

I can't seem to get anywhere near a correct answer ($Res(f;2i) = -3i/512$).  I'm supposed to use the Laurent expansion at $z=2i$ and ultimately find the $z^-1$ coefficient, but I'm so lost.... I've also tried partial fraction expansion, but am running in circles.  Engineering student here, so be nice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration is completely unnecessary here. More generally, never integrate if you can differentiate. And most of the times, geometric series is more than enough.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(z+2i)^3}&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dz^2}\frac{1}{(z-2i)+4i}\\
&=\frac12\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dz^2}\left[-\frac i4+\frac{1}{16}(z-2i)+\frac{i}{64}(z-2i)^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac{i}{64}-\frac{3}{256}(z-2i)-\frac{3i}{512}(z-2i)^2+\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\left[\frac{i}{64}-\frac{3}{256}(z-2i)-\frac{3i}{512}(z-2i)^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=\frac{i}{64}(z-2i)^{-3}-\frac{3}{256}(z-2i)^{-2}\color{red}{-\frac{3i}{512}(z-2i)^{-1}}+\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the formula
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n
$$
you should be able to write down a general formula for $a_n$, using the steps described above. I leave this to you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I assume the initial step is from the residue formula $$\operatorname{Res}(f,c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to c} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left( (z-c)^n f(z) \right)$$

Comment: Why is it that we expand the $\frac{1}{(z+2i)^3}$ term rather than the other?

Comment: I see now, using the fact that $$ \frac{\operatorname{d}^k}{\operatorname{d}\!z^k}\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \frac{k!}{(1-z)^{k+1}}$$.  Thanks again @AccidentalFourierTransform

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final answer (I use the physics package in Latex, sorry for the weird formatting in some areas):
\begin{align}
    f(z) &= \frac{1}{(z^2+4)^3}\\
      &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{(z+2i)^3}
  \end{align}
  Here, we see third order poles at $z=\pm2i$.  The Laurent series expansion of $f(z)$ about $z=2i$ should have the form,
  \begin{align}
    f(z) &= \frac{a_{-3}}{(z-z_0)^{-3}}+ \frac{a_{-2}}{(z-z_0)^{-2}} + \frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)} + a_0 + a_1(z-z_0) + a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots\\
\end{align}
To create an expandable geometric series for the $a_{-3}$ term, the following procedure can be used,
\begin{align}
    (z-z_0)^{3}f(z) &= a_{-3}+{a_{-2}}{(z-z_0)}+a_{-1}(z-z_0)^2 + a_0(z-z_0)^3 + a_1(z-z_0)^4 + a_2(z-z_0)^5+\cdots
  \end{align}
    Differentiating both sides, we find
  \begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dz^2}[(z-z_0)^{3}f(z)] &= (2\cdot1)a_{-1} + \sum_n^\infty b_n(z-z_0)^n\\
\end{align}
and in the limit where $z\to z_0$,
\begin{align}
a_{-1}& = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}[(z-z_0)^{3}f(z)]
  \end{align}
  which, of course, is the residue of the function at $z=2i$.  Therefore,
  \begin{align}
  f(z) &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(\frac{1}{(z+2i)})\\
  &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(
  \frac{1/4i}{(1+\frac{z-2i}{4i})})\\
  %
  &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{8i}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}[
  1-\frac{z-2i}{4i}
  +(\frac{z-2i}{4i})^2-(\frac{z-2i}{4i})^3
  +(\frac{z-2i}{4i})^4-(\frac{z-2i}{4i})^5
  +\cdots]\\
  %
  &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{8i}\frac{d}{dz}[
  -\frac{1}{4i}
  +\frac{2(z-2i)}{(4i)^2}-\frac{3(z-2i)^2}{(4i)^3}
  +\frac{4(z-2i)^3}{(4i)^4}-\frac{5(z-2i)^4}{(4i)^5}
  +\cdots]\\
  %
  &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{8i}[
  \frac{2\cdot1}{(4i)^2}-\frac{3\cdot2(z-2i)}{(4i)^3}
  +\frac{4\cdot3(z-2i)^2}{(4i)^4}-\frac{5\cdot4(z-2i)^3}{(4i)^5}
  +\cdots]\\
  %
  &= \frac{1}{(z-2i)^3}\frac{1}{8i}[
  \frac{2\cdot1}{(4i)^2}-\frac{3\cdot2(z-2i)}{(4i)^3}
  +\frac{4\cdot3(z-2i)^2}{(4i)^4}-\frac{5\cdot4(z-2i)^3}{(4i)^5}
  +\cdots]
  \end{align}
  After simplifying, we find the residue is $-3i/512$ and,
  \begin{equation}
\boxed{
f(z) = \frac{i}{64}(z-2i)^{-3}-\frac{3}{256}(z-2i)^{-2}
-\frac{3i}{512}(z-2i)^{-1}+\frac{5}{2048}+\cdots
}
  \end{equation}